# Create a Nested Dictionary in Powershell [HardCoded]

Tags: powershell, dictionary, nested

I want to create a dictionary, then adding an element to this dictionary. Also, another dictionary to this dictionary that I added later,
how can I achieve this? I tried to briefly summarize what I want to do below;

## My Dictionary

```
[hashtable]$CompItem = @{
    'ComputerName' = 'Microsoft Dell X'
    'ComputerDetails' = @{
      'motherboard' = 'MSI'
      'password' = "12345"
      'os' = "Windows"
    }
}
```

- How do I add a new entry to the dictionary?

```
$CompItem = @{ }                 # Create an nested emtpy dictionary
EX: $CompItem += { $CompItem.$ComputerDetails.Add( "hdd": "none" ) }
```

Comment: Just: `$CompItem.ComputerDetails['hdd'] = 'none'`

Comment: This is ok but what can I if I want to add a entry as dictionary to the existing entriy, for example, In CompItem, I want to add ```'users' = @{ 'receiver' = "john", 'buyer':  "who" }``` like that? @iRon

Comment: Just try what is most obvious: `$CompItem.users = @{ 'receiver' = "john", 'buyer':  "who" }`